# Storing and retrieving a large list in Ionic 2+

Tags: list, ionic-framework, storage, infinite-scroll

I aim to use the native storage plugin to store a potentially large list of objects in Ionic 3. I want to be able to then display the list in an Ionic infinite scrolling list. I presume that if I save the entire list to storage as a single object, with a single key, it will take quite some time to retrieve it, and the list page will remain empty for some time while the list is read asynchronously from storage.

Should I be saving each item in the list with an individual key, such as "key.1", "key.2", "key.3" etc, and then retrieving a "pageful" of items at a time, supported by the infinite scrolling list? The nuisance part of this is that when I want to add a new item to the list, I have to know what key number I'm up to, so I can generate the next key name.

What's the best practice for this scenario? Is there a better way to load a large list from memory asynchronously so that it can be displayed to the user as soon as possible?

Comment: if you use a large list, you could load it when your app start (create a service) and save it in a variable. When you access the page, the data will already be ready in said variable.

Comment: How did you resolve it in the end? I had same issue, I did tests and realized that I can read 1000+ small documents without big issues using local storage (Ionic Storage aka localForage). So I did 1 doc per key value approach. Reading full list - I am using forEach and push results into local variable.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up storing my items in a table in a SQLite database, as I wanted to avoid the size limitations that local storage can impose. I use a query like `SELECT * FROM submissions LIMIT ? OFFSET ?` to fetch a pageful of items at a time from the `doInfinite` function of an Ionic infinite scroller, keeping track of what page I'm up to and passing that into the OFFSET parameter. The LIMIT argument is the number of rows to fetch for a page, e.g. 10.